# How do you lay out your custom binary file format?

Tags: c++, serialization, layout

Every application has its own custom binary file format (e.g. .mpq, .wad).  On top of that, its commonly zipped.

So, my question is, how do you *artfully*/skillfully layout the binary contents of your file.  Do you have a "table of contents" like structure at the beginning?  Is it better to dump everything in one file?

So say you have an array of `Shapes`, and in each `Shape` is deformed vertex data (so the vertex data has changed from the file it was originally loaded from, so it should be saved anew).

```
class Shape
{
    vector<Vertex> verts ;
} ;

class Sphere : public Shape { } ; // ...more geometric shapes (Tet, Cube) are defined..

class Model : public Shape { } ; // general model "Shape" loaded from file

vector<Shape*> shapes ; // save me!  contents are mix of Model, Sphere, Tet..
// each with variable number of verts
```

Comment: would say that it depends to much on the data to be serialized. Really too general question to answer...

Comment: I'm really asking for techniques on how to map things. Let me update the question with an example

Comment: `Every application has its own custom binary file format` - only true in (a) Redmond (b) embedded/game programming; May I suggest Boost.Serialization for a good starting point?

Comment: +1 for boost::serialization. I use it and it works great (and it is FAST, too). As bonus, you get (if you want) XML serialization, which is nice for debugging and cross-arch compatibility. Combined with boost::streams, you can transparently compress the output.

Comment: You could try to find an existing file format which meets your requirements. You might also find a library to read/write that sort of data, or utilities to operate on data in that format. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorite article on the topic of file formats is at http://www.fadden.com/techmisc/file-formats.htm.

Beyond that, it probably comes down to what kind of data you are storing, and how that data will be used (will it be transmitted across a network, primarily?  How important is seek access?  Etc...).

Start with that article; it may help crystallize your thoughts if you already have a format that needs designing.

Answer (score 1):

In short - if your only need serialization, which means that you'll read and write from and to a stream, than you can use no-brainer here and emit your scructs member by member, or use any serialization library there is, from `CArchive to` .... whatever you see fancy.

If not, and you will have a need to directly access your data inside the file, then...  you'll use your requirements and they will, with some skill, tell you what will be layout of the file you are having.

And yeah, to broad topic to dwell here.  For example,

I have a need for a database of thumbnails for my software.  Each thumbnail has a timestamp, and I know that they will be of a different size.  Requirements are:

- sequential write (thumbs will be appended to the end of the database)
- thumbs will be appended in ascending order
- direct read (given time, get thumbnail in o(1) )
- no later modification to the database
- thumbnails will be in 15 seconds interval

Yes, requirements ARE simple here, but they stand for themselves.

I created two files, one with indexes and other with pictures.

Storing: append data file with image, append index file with index of the image in the data file.
Reading: find the index in the file using simple indexing ( index is `(timestamp-timestamp_start)/15` ).  Use that index to fetch image data.